# How do I resolve 'Id does not exist' error?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am building a calculator with flutter and after changing some of my code, I have been getting this error whenever I hot restart, I get this error:

```
======== Exception caught by Flutter framework =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during a service extension callback for "ext.flutter.inspector.setSelectionById":
Id does not exist.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      WidgetInspectorService.toObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:1283:7)
#1      WidgetInspectorService.setSelectionById (package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:1345:25)
#2      WidgetInspectorService._registerServiceExtensionWithArg.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:864:35)
#3      WidgetInspectorService._registerServiceExtensionWithArg.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:861:17)
#4      BindingBase.registerServiceExtension.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:597:32)
...

====================================================================================================
```

I have no clue what the error means and I cant find and answer to it anywhere.
The only thing I can infer is that it is possibly something with the inspector due to
`"ext.flutter.inspector.setSelectionById"`
but I honestly have no idea. I also believe it might not be to do with my code since it doesn't reference anything in there.
I would extremely appreciate if anyone could at least help me understand the error.
If you need more details, just ask me.

Comment: flutter inspector reminds me of the dart dev tools, could it be that you have dev tools open?

Comment: @user14624595 Hi, for some reason I just restarted the program instead of hot restarting and it stopped the error. Anyway, thank you for answering.

Comment: @user14624595 can you just enter an empty answer so I can close the thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The error was probably due to Flutter Dev Tools being open.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Do you have any explanation why is this happening? Seems to be a bug in Flutter's tools?

Comment: Hello, I cannot replicate the bug, I just know that the widget inspector is related to the GUI tools so perhaps there lies the problem. Please keep in mind that when the user posting this question restarted the app, there was no error, so my answer could also be a false one.

Answer (score 8):

I cannot explain why is this happening? But I solved the problem without restarting the whole app.

My Solution:

I just ran the following command:

```
flutter pub global activate devtools
```

It downloaded and compiled the dependencies needed for the `devtools` and reactivated the `devtools`.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I tried to show a CupertinoTimerPicker inside a SimpleDialog. I solved it by wrapping the CupertinoTimerPicker in a sized box with a defined height and width:

```
Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                  initialTimerDuration: tempDuration,
                  onTimerDurationChanged: (value) {
                    print(value.toString());
                    tempDuration = value;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. In my case I used a card widget without giving it a height or a width. The error message here needs to be improved by the flutter team.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/2824#issuecomment-806501806):

> I don't know if it's a Dart-Code, DevTools or Flutter bug...

Answer (score 2):

What helped me:

1. Stop flutter app on device
2. Delete `.dart_tool` and `build` folders from project tree.
3. Run fresh flutter app installation on device.

Answer (score 2):

For me, cleaning the project and rebuilding again solved the problem.

### Clean Command:

`flutter clean`

### Pub Get Command:

`flutter pub get`

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use DevTools and came up with these outputs in Debug Console, the suggested answers might not do good for you. Simply because some show you "how to avoid" it rather than solving. So, here's my 2 cents about solving this if you want to open up DevTools or Widget Inspector to debug your app.

This bug may have been fixed on newer versions (of devtools?) (or of Dart?) but I couldn't manage to solve it by simply "activating devtools globally". So I had to do some ugly stuff but eventually, I've managed to solve it.

---

**My fixpaghetti steps are as below**:

1. Stop debugging the app
2. Uninstall the app from device
3. Delete `<project-dir>/build` folder
4. run `flutter clean` from terminal
5. run `cd android && .\gradlew clean` (`cd android ; .\gradlew clean` if you're on powershell)
6. run `flutter pub global activate devtools`
7. run `flutter pub get` and wait for IDE to resolve errors (if it automatically does not, restart the IDE)
8. run the app

and add some prayers along the way. Hope you'll fix it!

Answer (score 2):

I just closed widget inspector. Restarted my app and then oppened widget inspector again, the error is gone.
Before I tryed restarting app without closing widget inspector, then after reading this post I understand that the infractor was the inspector so I decided to close and reopen it, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

After restarting the app it failed to build showing an error in app level build.gradle so

1. commented multidex true at default config    `//      multiDexEnable true`

[multidex xommenting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Nmt.png)
2. commented its implementation in the dependencies   `//  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`

[dependency commenting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjPCc.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but could fix it as follows;

Delete dart_tool and build folders.

Then run the following commands

- flutter clean
- flutter pub global activate devtools.
- flutter pub get

And restart IDE.

Answer (score -2):

You should close your compiler and open it again！！！
（maybe you've changed the ui so much）