# Id does not exist - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

My Flutter application's code throws a warning that the id does not exist when I try to run my code.

How can I ignore this warning?

```
======== Exception caught by Flutter framework =====================================================

The following assertion was thrown during a service extension callback for "ext.flutter.inspector.setSelectionById":
Id does not exist.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart 1297:7                     toObject
packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart 1359:25                    setSelectionById
packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart 867:35                     <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54            runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5            _async
packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart 864:38                     <fn>
packages/flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart 602:32                           <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1687:54                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 160:18                                    handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                    handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 593:7                                     [_complete]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart 390:15                                         <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:19       internalCallback
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve 'Id does not exist' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932705/how-do-i-resolve-id-does-not-exist-error)

Comment: no I this is same question as mine but this answers not help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
flutter pub global activate devtools
delete .dart_devtool folder
flutter clean
flutter pub get
run app
```

Answer (score 2):

- Close the app on your device.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to stop the app *or* just stop the app
- start up again